# How can I create a non-modal dialog in Perl/Tk?

Tags: perl, modalpopups, perltk

I am learning Perl/Tk. I want to give alert to the user whenever he/she receives the mail.

I have planned to use message box in Tk, but it is expecting the user to click ok or cancel button.

Until user clicked the any one button it wont do any further operations.

But I want, it just needs to give alert to the user and user can continue with the further process.

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're asking. How to create a new toplevel window? How to freeze everything else while you're waiting? (In that case, what is "everything else"?) can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It will be more easy to answer your query if you provide the code which causes error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the link

[Non blocking a Dialog box in Perl Tk](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=836513)